# Horizontally align div with display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table with bars in it. I use `display: table-cell` in order to align the contents at the bottom.  The problem is that the container `div`s no longer align horizontally over their corresponding `TH`s (their width is not set)

[Here is a jsFiddle that shows the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/gTWQ3/10/)

Comment: Are the graph bars supposed to be centered over the red `<th>`s? Could you post an image of how it's supposed to look?

Comment: To be more dynamic you can use the [jqBarGraph](http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/). Have you considered that possibility?

Comment: @Chris removed my answer as indeed it incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem

The problem when using the `table-cell`-attribute is that it behaves like "a real table cell" and no more like a `block`- or `inline`-element. When the parent elements `table-row`and `table` are missing they are generated anonymously. So the box will loose all the things like `margin`.

You can read more about this here: "[Tables in the visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#model)"

---

I rebuild your HTML structure a little and this seems to work fine:

#### DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/XPSQG/

#### CSS

```
<style>

    #graph th {
        background:         red;
    }

    #graph td {
        min-width:          30px;
        margin:             0;
        padding:            0;
        color:              #222222;
    }

    #graph div {
        display:            block;
        position:           relative;
        margin:             0 auto;
        width:              30px;
        max-width:          30px;
        height:             100px;
        background-color:   #EFEFEF;
        border:             1px solid #000000;
    }

    #graph span {
        position:           absolute;
        left:               0;
        top:                -20px;
        width:              100%;
        color:              #222222;
        font-size:          16px;
        line-height:        16px;
        text-align:         center;
    }

    #graph p.color {
        position:           absolute;
        right:              0;
        bottom:             0px;
        width:              100%;
        margin:             0;
        color:              #222222;
    }

    #graph p.color.c1 {
        background:         #0f0;
    }

    #graph p.color.c2 {
        background:         blue;
    }​

</style>
```

#### HTMl

```
<div id="graph">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div><p class="color c1" style="height:20px;"><span>1</span></p></div></td>
            <td><div><p class="color c2" style="height:30%;"><span>2</span></p></div></td>
            <td><div><p class="color c1" style="height:40%;"><span>3</span></p></div></td>
            <td><div><p class="color c2" style="height:50%;"><span>4</span></p></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>Some long value</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### How it works

It basically places the content (green percentage `<p>`-tags) of the columns on the bottom. To have the numbers **on top of that** you can easily place them within the `<p>`-tag and them "move them out" again. This is done by this part:

```
top:                -20px;
font-size:          16px;
line-height:        16px;
```

This says that the line-height and the font size are 16px. It would be enough to set `top: -16px` to move it out completely - the additional 4px add a nice padding. :)

Hope you get the idea.

#### Note

Somewhere you used this attribute:

```
countunit="0_1_0"
```

As this is not valid HTML please use the `data`-prefix:

```
data-countunit="0_1_0"
```

This is valid HTML5 and it also won't cause any trouble in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to center horizontally an element with display: table-cell inside another element.

Say the surrounding element has the class .table-wrapper and the inner element has .table-cell. Use the following CSS:

```
.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.table-cell {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This way you center the text or whatever you want inside .table-cell vertically and also horizontally.